# Suddenly unable to install application from SD card

Tags: applications, external-sd, installation

I have an HTC wildfire. I am currently developing an application which I am consistently testing on my phone. Since yesterday for some reason I am not able to install any apk of that particular app that I am building.

The usual method of installation I use is download to SD card and then install from there. Other apps get installed with this process but not my app.

The error message - App not installed.

I am able to download and install my app from the market.

I have tried deleting all information from the phone regarding the app i.e cache etc but still doesnt work.

Not sure if the phone has blocked my app ? Can it do that ..?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling completely and re-installing? Can you try installing it from a computer using `adb install -r [apk]`? This will give you a more detailed failure reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did an adb install -r [apk] thanks to the comment by @eldarerathis and I got an install_failed_container_error as the reason for installation failure...

Further searching got me to this link

http://eatingbits.se/articles/2010/11/16/install_failed_container_error-when-installing-an-application-on-android/

The solution being a temp file inside .android_secure folder not getting removed. So once i deleted the file app installed properly. Thanks everyone for helping out!!

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to "accept" this answer so it can act as a signpost for future readers.

Comment: I will!! Though I have to wait for a couple of days

Comment: Sometimes I think that Google needs to make it more publicly known that `adb install` gives you a detailed error message instead of "Oops, didn't work!" like the GUI does. That's such a esoteric reason for the install to fail that I can't imagine how anyone would figure it out otherwise (I had never even heard of this error). Not to say that you didn't already know this - I'm not sure if you did - but plenty of questions on Stack Overflow can be diagnosed the same way and most people seem to have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Apps>Settings>Applications, there look for Unknown Sources that is first option. Make sure it is ticked.

Comment: Yes it is, I've been installing the apk without any problems for quite a while now.

Comment: there shouldnt be other ways your android should block the apk.. maybe its the app that's not properly developed

Comment: Unfortunately even the previous versions which used to work fine aren't installing. Plus when I tried it on a different phone Samsung Galaxy I9000 it worked fine and there were no issues